# Is there a way to get global/system/Docker environment variables into a React app without .env?

Tags: reactjs, docker, environment-variables

I am building a .NET 6 + React app in Docker and having trouble accessing my Docker defined environment variables in my React frontend. The environment variables I define in my dockerfile like `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` is `undefined` when I try to access it in React with `process.env.ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT`. This environment variable is defined by the environment itself so gets passed as part of the `docker run` command with `-e`.

I do not believe I can pass these values in an `.env` file dynamically, say having `MY_VAR=$ENV_MY_VAL`.

Do you have any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: What image is your dockerfile based on? Does the image have a linux shell? An alternative to using environment variables is to implement something like what is shown here: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/title-and-meta-tags/#generating-dynamic-meta-tags-on-the-server

Comment: Doing some reading, it seems like your variable needs to start with `REACT_APP_` and you need node.js as an intermdiary to pass it into react.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid It appears that for some variables `REACT_APP_` does work, but when I  do `docker run --env REACT_APP_MY_VAR my-docker-image`, `REACT_APP_MY_VAR` is undefined. It also appears that the .net 6 react template has a node.js instance but I am not sure how to have it pass the variable to react.